# Any idea how i can use timeout command with condition in linux and shell script

Tags: linux, shell

aim working on some shell script , i would like to check the following command

df -h

if timeout more than 60 second then echo "error " else pass.

so if this command will not responding for 1 minute then I will receive and error message , otherwise it will pass , any creative idea will be high apricated .

Comment: There is a `timeout` command that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
timeout 60 df -h > /dev/null && echo "PASS" || echo "PROBLEM"
```

Using timeout, if the command df -h doesn't execute within 60 seconds or errors, it will return a none 0 return code. If a none 0 return code is returned echo "PROBLEM" using the || condition.

Comment: But can i just write an message instead of the whole command :
like if df -h work then "pass" otherwise "problem", is that possible ?

Comment: I have amended the answer

Comment: it still show me all the df -h and at end pass :(

Comment: You can add a redirect to /dev/null. I've amended the answer

Comment: `a && b || c` is an antipattern when used in place of `if a; then b; else c; fi`. Behavior is not identical. See [BashPitfalls #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3)